# Hide value of a input using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the information that is in an input text (a user's name, for example) when the anonymous check box is selected.

So, if I type my name inside the input text and after that I check the anonymous checkbox, my name will be hidden of the input.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is. Could you show your attempts and the markup?

Comment: Not sure this should be considered off-topic, since it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, not sure which one you want.

```
$("#yourCheckboxId").change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    // pick one of these options below
    if (checked) {
        // blank out the field
        $("#yourInputId").val("");
        // or hide it
        $("#yourInputId").hide();
    } else {
        $("#yourInputId").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working here: http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermeturatti/m6UHM/

Comment: @user2600853 You were missing a } brace. See http://jsfiddle.net/m6UHM/1/

Comment: That's true, my bad. Sorry.

Comment: Do you know why using the hide and show it doesn't work?
http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermeturatti/m6UHM/2/

Comment: @user2600853 missing periods. http://jsfiddle.net/m6UHM/3/

Comment: True. One more question, this one doesn't really brings back the text.
http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermeturatti/m6UHM/4/
Is possible to bring back the text when we uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: @user2600853 This one stores the value as an attribute on the input field and restores it when shown. http://jsfiddle.net/m6UHM/5/

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to hide it, you can change the `type` to `password` to mask the characters:

```
$("#yourCheckboxId").change(function() {
    $("#yourInputId").attr("type", function() {
        var current = $(this).attr("type");
        return current == "text" ? "password" : "text";
    });
});
```

Comment: You will run into browser security directives with this: http://jsfiddle.net/hJ689/  

Throws: `Error: type property can't be changed`